# Automapper: How to map one source to multiple destinations

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I have the following sample entities:

```
public class User
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    pubilc HashSet<UserRole> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public HashSet<UserRole> Users { get; set; }
}

public class UserRole
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

and the following Dtos:

```
public class UserModel
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    pubilc HashSet<RoleModel> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class RoleModel
{
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public HashSet<UserModel> Users { get; set; }
}
```

with the following AutoMapper configuration:

```
CreateMap<User, UserModel>();

CreateMap<Role, RoleModel>();

CreateMap<UserRole, UserModel>()
    .ConstructUsing((src, ctx) => ctx.Mapper.Map<UserModel>(src.User));

CreateMap<UserRole, RoleModel>()
    .ConstructUsing((src, ctx) => ctx.Mapper.Map<RoleModel>(src.Role));
```

but this configuration causes the iis to stop without any error!

Is this configuration right for mapping one source into multiple destinations?

[Github test project](https://github.com/SalehGladius/AutomapperTest)

Comment: I just installed Automapper 9.0.0 to .NET Framework WinForms project, copied your code, changed the configuration code to use `MapperConfiguration`, ran it, and configuration was created without errors. Please make a small test project and copy there only the code you feel is relevant and investigate from there.

Comment: @Dialecticus you can use this github project to see what I say, [repo](https://github.com/SalehGladius/AutomapperTest)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is good approach to use such a mapping or not. But the problem is for an infinite loop which occurs in the mapping (nested mapping maybe).

[image: StackOverflowException]

[image: UserA]

Following codes which are commented is the source of loop:

[image: Loop Source]

Answer (score 1):

You could try to the following mapping :

```
public MapperConfig()
    {
        CreateMap<User, UserModel>();

        CreateMap<UserRole, RoleModel>()
            .ForMember(des=>des.RoleName,opt=>opt.MapFrom(src=>src.Role.RoleName));

        CreateMap<Role, RoleModel>();
        CreateMap<UserRole, UserModel>()
            .ForMember(des => des.Username, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.User.Username))
            .ForMember(des => des.Password, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.User.Password));

    }
```